# How to use Substitute command to change something in the middle of the pattern?

Tags: vim, sed

My case is as follows :

I have a bunch of functions and declarations in the type `myStuffDoSomething` that I want to rename to `myStuff_DoSomething`, where `DoSomething` could be any word. And there is a chance that some of them are alredy written like that.

I could use `s/myStuff[^_]/&_/g` but that will end with myStuffD_oSomething putting the underscore in the wrong place.

NOTE: I added sed to the tags because the command substitute has the similar syntax as sed (if not the same).

Comment: Although the `s///` syntax is the same, vim and sed regular expression differ. sed does not have `\zs`

Comment: I understand that. But I added the `sed` tag so that someone knowing `sed`, but not `vim` might see it and still give an useful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the name already contains a `_` you can just use `s/myStuff\zs_\?/_/g` as long as the prefix is always myStuff.
This way an existing `_` will not be doubled, but a non existing one will be inserted.

**EDIT:** Used `\zs` token to remove duplication as pointed out by [Randy Morris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155299/randy-morris) in the comments.

Comment: I think I don't understand the problem you mean - I understood the question in the way that ALL functions starting with myStuff should be underscored (which the simple sed function should do - it just replaces myStuff AND myStuff_ with myStuff_ no matter what follows - yes even if NOTHING follows - so that case would probably be wrong) - do you mean that case when an unneccessary underscore is added? That might be fixed with a lookahead - if needed - but I try to keep it simple until the solution must become more complex.

Comment: Oops. My bad. I dint read this "where DoSomething **could be any word**"

Comment: Well at least now my comment highlights when this sed-function won't work and might need additional work.

Comment: A little better way of doing that removes duplication: `s/myStuff\zs_\?/_`

Comment: I didn't know about `\zs` but it seems incredibly useful for some one-off regexes that come up every now and again - thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dimitar Slavchev: Actually the regular expression is fairly straight forward: the first part `/myStuff\zs_\?/` just looks for `myStuff` or `myStuff_` (you already have some underscored) and \zs resets the start of the match to the token before the optional underscore - the second part `/_/` inserts an `_` or replaces an `_` with an `_` - thanks to `\zs` the match that is replaced in only the optinal `_` and not the whole search term.

Comment: @glennjackman `:help /\zs`.  There are others there that are just as useful once you know about them.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
echo myStuffDoSomething | sed 's/\(myStuff\)\([^_]\)/\1_\2/'
myStuff_DoSomething
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do:

```
%s/\(myStuff\)_*/\1_
```